# Io language user input

Tags: iolanguage

I recently started messing around with the Io programming language and think it's pretty fun and simple to learn.  But I also hate that there is so little documentation and support for it.  Normally I come to SO for help, but even on here the topic is sparse.

I am learning from the 7 languages in 7 weeks book, which I like, but there he mainly talks about the deeper uses of Io.

My question is probably extremely simple but I can't find an answer anywhere...  How do you actually ask a user for input?  I've found ways to pass along set strings, read in strings from files, but I can't find a way to ask a user for input.

What I'm working on now is writing a function that accepts 2 parameters: a string and a substring to find in that string.  The function finds the substring in the string and prints the index.  I don't even know if I should be asking the user for input or doing this another way...

I'm trying to get some keyboard time in on Io but it's frustrating :/

Also, does anyone know of any IRC channels that are friendly to beginners? Not necessarily just Io, but in general?

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On the topic of IRC, there's `irc.freenode.net` and the `#io` channel. We're not always active, but if you hang around, I usually poke in at least once a day.

On the topic of user input however, You can do this:

`x := File standardInput readLine`

This will get a single line of input, up to where the user hit the enter/return key, and capture that in `x`.

Comment: Thanks for the tips!  Very much appreciated.  Regarding the #io channel, do you know of a general channel?  Noe necessarily specific to Io?

Comment: Depends really on what you're looking for.